# Saxophone pearl key is down by default

Tags: saxophone

I am new to saxophone and I was just learning to play my first notes when I came across the G# where it needs a certain pearl key to be pressed in order to play but I already found that key to be down by default, is this a problem with my instrument or am I missing something?

Comment: It is very difficult to give an answer to this question as there simply is too little information. You need to describe exactly which key you are referring to. Best is however to meet someone with a little more knowledge. It could be a simple fix that is needed. My guess (and I do not play any saxophone) is that one nedled spring has slipped out of its seeting. I believe the G# key is left hand little finger? and that might have happened. This would leave the G# hole open all the time making it quite difficult to play lower notes.

Comment: As ghellquist said, the spring for the key may have slipped off the notch that holds it (the most common problem) or is possibly  broken or missing.

Comment: As mentioned it is difficult to answer without more information.
A further problem is that for G# one is not pressing a certain key. For a G# you press all three keys of the left hand (resulting in G) and one of the levers for the left little finger. But this lever usually has no pearl.
Is it possible, you meant a F#? As for this note you press the middle finger of the right hand on the key.

Answer (score 2):

As the comments suggest, this is almost certainly due to a missing or misaligned return spring.

However, the real problem -- Root Cause Analysis -- is that you should absolutely not try to learn on your own.  Take lessons with a saxophone teacher. He or she will immediately be able to identify any possible mechanical problems with your instrument.

Answer (score 2):

The pad that the G# key operates is normally closed. That's the way the instrument is designed. You have to depress the G# key to **open** that hole.

Comment: OP was referring to the key and not the pad.

Comment: @Duston It's unclear exactly what OP is referring to, but unless there is major damage to the instrument, there is almost no way the key itself could be stuck down. And even if it was, the hole would be open and G wouldn't be possible

Answer (score 1):

You may be referring to the G# "trill key" that is only found (at least in my experience) on some older horns.  I have a vintage King H.N. White alto made in Cleveland in the late 1920s.  It has a pearl trill key between the low F and E keys.  It remains "slack" (i.e., in the down position, incapable of being pressed) until one depresses the standard G# key on the side of the horn (i.e., the key at the top of the key panel that contains the low Bb, B and C# keys).  When you play that standard G# key, the trill key activates (i.e. raises) and allows you an easy (or easier) way of trilling the G#, instead of trying that maneuver on the standard G# key, which is more awkward and probably involves more key noise too. Not sure why the trill key doesn't show up on more modern horns except maybe trilling the G# was a popular big band arrangement move.